# Problem with if command -> set -> echo in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm going to make a Windows batch file with a variable called %ProductKey%. I have the code which determines the version of Windows(Which is the variable %WINVER%).
It should set the ProductKey variable with if command and echo %ProductKey%, which should be XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX.

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (`WMIC OS Get Caption ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do set WINVER=%%i
if "%WINVER%" == "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" ( set ProductKey=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX )
echo %ProductKey%
pause
```

%WINVER% is Microsoft Windows 10 Pro for my PC.

It should display me XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX which is the product key, it shows me just echo is off.

Comment: Turn `echo on` and watch how your `if` line is executed. Consider `for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1 delims=|" %%i in (`WMIC OS Get name ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do...`

Comment: Do `for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('wmic OS get Caption') do for /F "delims=" %%J in ("%%I") do set "WINVER=%%J"` to avoid artifacts from Unicode-to-ASCII/ANSI conversion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you add a line

```
echo "%WINVER%"
```

before the "if" test.

With Windows 10 Home, this shows **"Microsoft Windows 10 Home  "**. I can't test with Windows 10 Pro, but my intuition tells me that Pro will also show those trailing spaces.

Perhaps

```
if "%WINVER: =%" == "MicrosoftWindows10Pro" ...
```

will cure your problem.

Comment: Wow... Solved at just ONCE.